# Игнорирование повторов в регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текстовый массив из которого надо отобрать трёхзначные числовые значения, но проблема в том, что каждое числовое значение последотвательно дублируется через текстовый промежуток.

Условно представить его можно так:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ***179*** Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ***179*** Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. ***250*** Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, ***250*** sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

И при отборе методом `\d{3}` получается массив ровно вдвое больше из-за дубликатов.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как оптимизировать регулярное выражение, чтобы игнорировать дубликаты.

Comment: Было бы хорошо привести этот массив с желаемым результатами.

Comment: Да, конечно. Спасибо за напоминанание). Добавила пример в пост.

Comment: А не проще ли полученный массив отфильтровать?

Comment: Если других вариантов не найдётся, то придётся отфильтровывать. Но хотелось бы отсеять дубликаты на этапе сбора.

Comment: Ээээээ, нечего удалять вопросы, на которые ответили.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ахахахахах

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю среди одинаковых чисел брать только последнее вхождение. Только обращаю внимание, что этот алгоритм приводит к квадратичной сложности вместо линейной, так что гораздо эффективнее было бы сначала вытащить все числа, а потом отфильтровать массив.

```js
var s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 179 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 179 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 250 Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 250 sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

console.log(s.match(/(?<!\d)(\d+)(?!\d)(?!.*\D\1(?!\d))/g))
```